# Help in identifying JC higgins year?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

The markings are MOD 502 42430 120647
[image: close-up of the underside of a blue-painted bottom bracket showing the numbers above]

Comment: This may give some insight: https://ratrodbikes.com/forum/threads/detailed-higgins-serial-number-decoder.51973/

Comment: J.C Higgins bikes were sold by Sears. Here is a [link to Sears catalogs](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/)